# Make executable using android ndk on linux without Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, executable, bin, ndk-build

is it possible to make executable binary without using android studio on linux?

example

```sh
adb shell /system/bin/ifconfig
```

log

```sh
Encap link: Local Loopback
           inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
           RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
           RX bytes:524428 TX bytes:524428
........ more
```

For this example, the executable doesn't need to do anything in particular—just hello world code is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle and the Android plugin run independent of Android Studio. This means that you can build your Android apps from within Android Studio, the command line on your machine, or on machines where Android Studio is not installed (such as continuous integration servers). If you are not using Android Studio, you can learn how to build and run your app from the command line. The output of the build is the same whether you are building a project from the command line, on a remote machine, or using Android Studio.

source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - they're trying to make an executable binary, not an app.